# How to use Dynamics variables in layout properties?

Tags: android, variables, layout, dynamic, global

Hi i'm a new developer in Android

and i want to create global variable to put them in my Layout like that:

in Java:`final dimen myglobalValue = screenSize.width;
final dimen myglobalValue2 = screenSize.height;`

in Layout:

```
    <TextView
android:layout_width="@dimen/myglobalValue"
android:layout_height="@dimen/myglobalValue2"
android:text="@string/app_name"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

but in don't know how to do.

Comment: better get familiar with the android layout. Using hard-coded sizes is not good practice. Use "fill_parent" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that; in general, you cannot modify resources at run time.

What you can do:

- in the code (java), after inflating the layout, you can specify other values for the width and height of the view; though I'd not recommend it.
- if you just want the view to be as wide and high as the display, use:

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  for the TextView and its parent ViewGroup (LinearLayout, etc.). A bit of XML polishing might be required to remove margins, etc.

Comment: yes, but i want to change the width and the height AUTOMATICALY, for all the resolutions of devices, if the guy have a 800x400 resolution, the item's will take the width and the height adapt to it.
Or explain me how can i change the size of an element in my .java?
thx a lot for help anyway.

Comment: That's the point of 'fill_parent': it takes the whole available space. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT

Comment: So, can i use fill_parrent/2 if i want than my item will do the half of my screen ?
like android:layout_height="fill_parent/2"

Comment: Nope; you'll need more advanced techniques (see layout_weight). I suggest you read carefully the Android layout documentation, and review the provided samples.

Comment: i have already saw it, i'm sure it work with the weight method, to adapt the layouts size, but i really dislike this method, in all the other languages, i can change the size of my items directly from the .java file (like the "m" file in Ios) i really want to do it in Java too, but if you say it's impossible i trust you, thx for help